# How to create Corner Ribbon in Android XML Code? I need like below images design

Tags: android, android-layout

Sample Corner Ribbon Example 1:
[image: Sample Corner Ribbon Example 1]

Sample Corner Ribbon Example 2:
[image: Sample Corner Ribbon Example 2]

Comment: Please add more details and include what you have tried so far to make it easier for others to help

Answer (score 1):

You could probably build this ribbon with xml drawable but that would be extremely difficult. And you would need more than one drawable + rotation.

A better approach would be to use a square vector image instead and display it on top of your layout.